# Open plain text files with LightTable by default when double-clicking them (in ubuntu 14.04 64bits)

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, lighttable

I put LightTable in /opt/LightTable

By default, when you install the text editor LightTable in ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, you don't have an "open with LightTable" when you right-click the file you want to open with it.

Therefore I created a file /home/theuser/.local/share/applications/LightTable.desktop containing :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LighTable Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=/opt/LightTable/LightTable %f
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/LightTable/core/img/lticon.png
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain
```

so that a "open with LightTable" appears when I want open a file with LighTable. Now, the problems begin. When I do this, it only opens LightTable, as if I only ran the script

```
/opt/LightTable/LightTable
```

Therefore I went to see the script :

```
#!/bin/bash

BIN=ltbin
HERE=`dirname $(readlink -f $0)`

LIBUDEV_0=libudev.so.0
LIBUDEV_1=libudev.so.1

add_udev_symlinks() {
  # 64-bit specific; look for libudev.so.0, and if that can't be
  # found link it to libudev.so.1
  FOLDERS="/lib64 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64 /usr/lib /lib"

  for folder in $FOLDERS; do
    if [ -f "${folder}/${LIBUDEV_0}" ]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done

  for folder in $FOLDERS; do
    if [ -f "${folder}/${LIBUDEV_1}" ]; then
      ln -snf "${folder}/${LIBUDEV_1}" "${HERE}/${LIBUDEV_0}"
      return 0
    fi
  done

  echo "${LIBUDEV_0} or ${LIBUDEV_1} not found in any of ${FOLDERS}".
  exit 1
}

add_udev_symlinks

ARGS="$@"

CORRECTED=${ARGS//-/<d>}
CORRECTED=${CORRECTED// /<s>}

if [ -t 0 ] && [ $# != 0 ]; then
  #We're in a terminal...
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" $HERE/$BIN "<d><d>dir=`pwd`<s>$CORRECTED" &
else
  #We were double clicked
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" $HERE/$BIN &
fi
```

and replaced its ending if/else/fi by a simple :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" $HERE/$BIN "<d><d>dir=`pwd`<s>$CORRECTED" &
```

so that the right behaviour (the one when opening a file from the terminal) is chosen.

This almost made my day. Now, if I double-click a file or right-click it and select "open with LightTable", the file is indeed opened in LightTable... but : **this is true only if the file name and the path to the file have no blank space in their names**.

If the file named "the file" is in the path thepath without space in it, when I double-click it, it opens two blank files "the" and "file" in LightTable. The same behavior is constated if thepath has space(s) in it.

Would someone have an idea ? I guess I should correct the bash script, but I'm not an expert in it. (I am not even sure that the script is really wrong...)

Thanks in advance

MEF

Comment: I tried the same patch and am facing the same issue. It seems like the issue is with Light Table's parsing of the cli args: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/blob/master/src/lt/objs/cli.cljs Notice how it splits blindly everything that has a space in it. Not sure whether there is a workaround...

Comment: I just reported the issue at: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1688

Comment: Actually I already reported it :
https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1659
You should maybe revert your report, because the issue is apparently already assigned to someone from lighttable's tean. Thx nevertheless for your initiative !

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a tl;dr quality about it.

When you store `"$@"` in a variable, you really have to use an array and lots of quotes to preserve the elements with whitespace:

```
ARGS=("$@")
CORRECTED=("${ARGS[@]//-/<d>}")
CORRECTED=("${CORRECTED[@]// /<s>}")
```

But then the way you have to pass the args is a problem:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" $HERE/$BIN "<d><d>dir=`pwd`<s>$CORRECTED" &
```

It's impossible to expand the array into a  single space-delimited string and then somehow extract the elements that have significant whitespace.
You may have to do this, and see if it works:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"   # might as well put on own line
"$HERE/$BIN" "<d><d>dir=`pwd`<s>" "${CORRECTED[@]}" &
# ...........^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ standalone argument
```

Comment: Thx for you answer. I am just giving it a try and the result of double-clicking a plain text file is now the opening of an empty instance of LightTable.

Wrt the too long didn't read issue, I would say that I added the strict minimum of needed info : config, what I tweaked already, plus the script. Don't see how to shorten it without being imprecise... But I'll try to do better next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a bug in LightTable.

I opened an issue (https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1762) and submitted a patch (https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/pull/1763) to fix this :

> There are 2 issues here:
>
> - currently the deployed Bash script doesn't pass any arguments to LightTable if it's not invoked from a terminal, but this is needed e.g. to make a gnome desktop shortcut. This issue can also be reproduced by using the ALT+F2 launcher under Ubuntu.
> - independently LightTable cannot currently open files whose names contain ' ' characters.

Comment: Fine. Thx ! After this, lighttable will be almost perfect.